# Best way to setup Rails Resque on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I'm building some middleware to look for and process incoming files.

I've setup Resque to queue and execute jobs.

What is the best way to setup my Ubuntu server to keep the resque process running 24x7 so jobs are executed and if the process stops for some reason to start it up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `process monitor` such as [god](http://god.rubyforge.org/), [bluepill](https://github.com/arya/bluepill) and [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to achieve what you require.
Resque includes some example configurations to get you started with god and monit:

- https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/examples/monit/resque.monit
- https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/master/examples/god

Comment: just to update links: https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/monit/resque.monit and https://github.com/resque/resque/tree/master/examples/god